# How to save the null values from a Dataset to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have strict requirement, to save the null values to the Mongodb, as I am aware of the case of nosql where storing null is not recommended but my business requirement have a scenario.

a sample csv file which has a null value

```
a,b,c,id
,2,3,A
4,4,4,B
```

*code to save csv to mongodb*

```
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
                DataTypes.createStructField("a",  DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("b", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("c", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, true),

        });
        Dataset<Row> g  = spark.read()
                .format("csv")
                .schema(schema)
                .option("header", "true")  
                .option("inferSchema","false")

                .load("/home/Documents/SparkLogs/a.csv");



        MongoSpark.save(g
                .write()
        .option("database", "A")
                .option("collection","b").mode("overwrite")
                )

        ;
```

*Mongodb Output*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d663b6bec20c94c990e6d0c"),
    "a" : 4,
    "b" : 4,
    "c" : 4,
    "id" : "B"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d663b6bec20c94c990e6d0d"),
    "b" : 2,
    "c" : 3,
    "id" : "A"
}
```

My requirement is to have a 'a' field will null type in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving as DataSet with `MongoSpark` will ignore the null value keys defaultly. So my workaround is to convert Dataset to javaPairRDD of BsonObject types.

*Code*

```
/** imports ***/
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.beans.Encoder;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.bson.BSONObject;
import org.bson.BasicBSONObject;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat;
/** imports ***/



private static void saveToMongoDB_With_Null(Dataset<Row> ds, Configuration outputConfig,String [] cols) {
        JavaPairRDD<Object,BSONObject> document =   ds
                .toJavaRDD()
                .mapToPair(f -> {

                     BSONObject doc = new BasicBSONObject();

                     for(String p:cols)
                         doc.put(p, f.getAs(p));

                        return new Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>(null, doc);

                });

        document.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
                    "file:///this-is-completely-unused"
                , Object.class
                , BSONObject.class
                , MongoOutputFormat.class
                , outputConfig);
    }



    Configuration outputConfig = new Configuration();
    outputConfig.set("mongo.output.uri",
                     "mongodb://192.168.0.19:27017/database.collection");
  outputConfig.set("mongo.output.format", 
                      "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat");

 Dataset<Row> g  = spark.read()
                .format("csv")
                .schema(schema)
                .option("header", "true")  
                .option("inferSchema","false")

                .load("/home/Documents/SparkLogs/a.csv");

    saveToMongoDB_With_Null(g, outputConfig,g.columns());
```

**Needed Maven Dependency**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop/mongo-hadoop-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**MongoDB output after workflow**

```
{
    "_id" : "a62e9b02-da97-493b-9563-fc19054df60e",
    "a" : null,
    "b" : 2,
    "c" : 3,
    "id" : "A"
}

{
    "_id" : "fed373a8-e671-44a4-8b85-7c7e2ff59585",
    "a" : 4,
    "b" : 4,
    "c" : 4,
    "id" : "B"
}
```

**Downsides**

Bringing the high-level api like Dataset to low-level rdds will loose the spark's ability to optimise the queryplans , so trade-off is performance.